# Display document in an iframe for all devices

Tags: html, iframe, document

I am developing a website use by PC, Tablet and smartphone and i am trying to display a document in an iframe. I read a lot of post but I'm stuck.

I have a component html with an iframe inside:

```
<iframe src="http//..myDoc.pdf"></iframe>
```

On computer it works fine and the iframe display the document. 
But I have two problems:

1) On android (tablet Samsung and smartphone Samsung), the document is not display and it is downloading automatically instead.

What I need to do for avoid download the document and for only display it?

2) On iPhone (6s), the document is displayed but the document's size exceeds the ifame'size.

How can I do to fit all the document in the iframe?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer and It works on all devices.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://..myDoc.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I need to display sensitive data. Is it a secure way to use the docs.google.com/gview ?

If I need to do something to secure the iframe, can someone tell me please?

Thank you